# How to query multiple tables for a record where tables have identical column names

Tags: mysql, sql, select, mariadb

I have a database with two tables, switches and routers.  The columns in both tables have identical names (dev_name, dev_ip, etc).

I need to know how to query both tables and find the individual record that has a specific hostname.  So, if my PHP form is to query the database by device name, I want to query the entire database (all tables) and find the table/row that has the device being queried for.

I've tried a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM switches,routers 
WHERE switches.dev_name = 'coreswitch01' OR routers.dev_name = 'core01switch';
```

but it gives me a concatenated output that includes every router in the router table and coreswitch01 repeatedly.

```
SELECT * FROM switches,routers 
WHERE switches.dev_name = 'coreswitch01' OR routers.dev_name = 'core01switch';
```

What I'm hoping to structure is a query that reads through both tables and finds the record for coreswitch01 and just shows me that one record from whatever table it finds it in.

Comment: just to help you understand why you are seeing the results that you are, the `,` between the two table names is a shorthand syntax for a `JOIN` query;  that's where the row concatenation comes from;  further, without a `JOIN` condition, your results are a Cartesian join, and that's where the repetition comes from; HTH; the answer from Mureinik is an excellent, concise answer for what you want to actually achieve

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `union all` set operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT * FROM switches
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM routers) t
WHERE  dev_name = 'coreswitch01'
```

Comment: This formulation will do 3 full passes over all the data -- once to find all the rows in each table, a second time to write them to a temp table, and a third time to search the un-indexed temp table for the desired row(s).  Very inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I see two tables with identical (or nearly identical) columns, I ask "Why are these two tables not combined into a single table?"  You *may* need an extra column to say which kind of thingie it is (router vs switch), but that is a minor overhead.

But, given that you have 2 tables...

For your particular query, this is optimal:

```
( SELECT * FROM switches  WHERE dev_name = 'coreswitch01' )
UNION ALL
( SELECT * FROM routers   WHERE dev_name = 'coreswitch01' )
```

This assumes you have an index on `dev_name` in each table.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new fields like "origin" if you want determine the data table origin :

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT 'switches' as origin, * FROM switches
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'routers'  as origin, * FROM routers) t
WHERE  dev_name = 'coreswitch01'
```